# Issue with removing custom metafield value in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a like system in wordpress. I have done a page in which it will list all liked post by an user. http://learnwordpresspro.com/like-front-end/ I want to keep a remove button which will remove the like from front end also from this lists. I am very much confused. For displaying list of post i have done following code. I want to keep a remove button which needs to remove post like when it was submitted

```
<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="user_likes"><?php _e( 'You Like:', 'YourThemeTextDomain' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
        <?php
        $types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ) );
        $args = array(
          'numberposts' => -1,
          'post_type' => $types,
          'meta_query' => array (
            array (
              'key' => '_user_liked',
              'value' => $user->ID,
              'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
          ) );      
        $sep = '';
        $like_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $like_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <p>
        <?php while ( $like_query->have_posts() ) : $like_query->the_post(); 
        echo $sep; ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php
        $sep = ' &middot; ';
        endwhile; 
        ?>
        </p>
        <?php else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'You do not like anything yet.', 'YourThemeTextDomain' ); ?></p>
        <?php 
        endif; 
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So you want to add a button to unlike the post? If so, I'd go with Ajax for this. Check here for a few examples: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wordpress+ajax+button

Comment: @cabrerahector I don't need ajax for this.

Comment: Alright then. Good luck!